# Existence of a subgroup that is isomorphic to G

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G=Hol(C_8)$. In addition let $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $8$, $L$ a splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and suppose that $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})\cong G$

> How to show that there is a subgroup of $S_8$ isomorphic to $G$

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose that you are intending to use some Galois theory to prove this, but you can also observe that the holomorph of $C_8$ is the normalizer of the permutation subset of $[8]$ induced by left multiplication of $C_8$ on itself, and $\text{Sym}(8) = S_8$.

Comment: and how to show that they are isomorphic ?